# Creating a new list from two lists where one has missing data - only valid corresponding values should be accepted

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, list

Hello I am writing a script in Python 2.7 to joint two separate lists and to create a new one without missing values but with corresponding indexes (see example for better explanation).
Let's assume that I have extracted two lists from a source dataset:

- List 1 - with parameter (e.g. year)
- List 2 - with parameter's value

However, not all parameters have values in list 2 (missing data). The task is to create two lists that will allow to plot a graph based only on the complete data (pairs).

Currently I'm using the script below which works fine.

My question: is there any easier method to do this?

Especially when there are couple of lists with missing data this method would become more and more difficult to manage. Or when extracted list will have NaN instead of empty string "".

Any ideas, libraries?

```
list1 = [2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007]
list2 = [0,1,2,3,"",5,"",7]

list1_reduced = [] 
list2_reduced = []

i=0
for element in list2:
    if element != "":
        list1_reduced.append(list1[i])
        list2_reduced.append(list2[i])
    i += 1

print list1_reduced
print list2_reduced
```

Result:

```
[2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2005, 2007]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
```

I use Python 2.7 (Anaconda), Spyder IDE, Windows 10.

Any help very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: please mark you question as resolved in chosing the best answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007]
list2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, "", 5, "", 7]

list1, list2 = [list(z) for z in
                    zip(*[(x, y) for (x, y) in
                          zip(list1, list2) if y != ''])]

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Result:

```
[2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2005, 2007]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Pretty cool (+1). Just one setback: both lists turn to tuples not as lists.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac now it is list

Comment: @glegoux Nice job! It works fine. I tried before with zip() function but I couldn't find the way to perform the logical test. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
[(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(list1, list2) if y != '']
```

An alternative test is testing for type is integer: `isinstance(y, int)` instead of `y != ''`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a viable solution:

```
list1 = [2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007]
list2 = [0,1,2,3,"",5,"",7]

reducedIndexes = [i for i,x in enumerate(list2) if x != '']

list1_reduced = [list1[i] for i in reducedIndexes] 
list2_reduced = [list2[i] for i in reducedIndexes]
```

Contents of the reduced lists:

```
[2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2005, 2007]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
```